# plot histogram with "range" data

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, seaborn

i'm trying to plot data from a csv file the data is represented as follows

```
xi,ni
"20-40",240
"40-60",208
"60-80",160
"80-100",212
"100-140",129
"140-200",51
```

So the **ni** is number of times we observed a value in the **xi** range.

Using pandas and seaborn i want to visualize the data with the x axis ranging from 0 to 200 with a 10 step but i only managed to display the "20-40"etc. as a class in the graph.
 Here's my code and the result i got:

```
import seaborn as sns
from random import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("./ex3.csv")
sns.barplot(x=df['xi'],y=df['ni'])
#sns.distplot(df['ni'])
```

[image: output]

Thanks by advance

Comment: Can you add last 3-4 rows of data for visualize to question?

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't quite get your question, do you want me to add the result of "data.tail()" to my question body ? or is it something else ?

Comment: I think how are changed `"100-140",129
"140-200",51` rows for 10 bins step.

Comment: again i'm not quite getting what you want me to do, should i add more rows between 100 and 200 so that seaborn interprets it as a range ?

Comment: I think how are changed sample data for display by 10 bins? I ask because is necessary some operation with datafrmae before plot.

Comment: oooh well so if i'd like to have a bar that starts from 100 and stops at 139 and is 129 units high 
the data wouldn't have to be changed

Comment: yes, so how are data ditributed to 110, 120, 130, 140 groups?

Comment: or 100-110, 110-120 120-130, 130-140

Comment: i'm not considering the repartition inside groups so i would have a single group but the axis would range like 100-110-120-130-140 etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201016/discussion-between-jezrael-and-slite).